# Tengo un error al intentar ingresar credenciales de configuracion de pktriot en linux

Tags: linux, certificado-ssl

Este es el error: Password: Login failure: Post "https://packetriot.com:443/api/v1.0/client/init/login": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Alguien me podria orientar